# Programmatically printing WebBrowser and setting its PrinterSettings in VB

Tags: vb.net, printing

I am trying to find a way to set `PrinterSettings` when printing contents of WebBrowser similar to the following code

```
Dim doc As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument()
With doc
     .PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings()
     With .PrinterSettings
          .PrinterName = "PrinterName"
          .PrintToFile = True
          .PrintFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.pdf")
     End With
End With
doc.Print()
```

I converted this from a C# code I've found that tells how to set `PrinterSettings` programmatically.

Is there a way to combine the code above with `WebBrowser.Print()` in order to print HTML and set `PrinterSettings` programmatically

I have tried doing it like this thinking that this code might set default printer to `Microsoft Print to PDF`

```
Dim doc As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument()
With doc
     .PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings()
     With .PrinterSettings
          .PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
          .PrintToFile = True
          .PrintFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.pdf")
     End With
End With
WebBrowser.Print()
```

But it prints on the default printer and not on `Microsoft Print to PDF`

Edit: The WebBrowser contains the document I'm trying to print in HTML Format and some inline CSS. The WebBrowser don't have a UI, It is a plain code Declared as `Private WithEvents WebBrowser As WebBrowser`. Hope this helps clear my problem, thanks.

Edit(2): Setting the Default Printer have been problematic to me because of the printer setting "let windows manage my printers." Unchecking this allow the application to set the default printer. *credits to K J*

Comment: The documentation only explain printing image and text. I don't think I've seen something about controls like WebBrowser.  Thanks Though, I will try to dig deeper in the docs. I might find something useful for other parts of my issue.

Comment: I've seen something like this where it rewrites some system scripts(maybe) to set the default printer. Sadly it still uses the previous default printer. Here's the [link](http://rani-irsan.blogspot.com/2019/10/vbnet-setting-default-printer-with.html) to the code

Comment: I see. This actually solves one of my major problem(Default printer not setting up properly) but open up another problem. So there's no possible way to programmatically choose MS Print to PDF without changing this setting. I am trying to make my application as foolproof as possible but this makes it harder. Thanks! I'll Update my question with this info.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :
Vote for me if I've helped you.

```
    Dim doc As New PrintDocument()
    With doc
        With .PrinterSettings
            .PrinterName = "PrinterName" ' exam: Fax
            .PrintToFile = True
            .PrintFileName = "The location of the file you want to print with the formula" ' exam -> C:\CV.pdf
        End With
    End With
    doc.Print()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am Trying to print Webbrowser(HTML document). As I stated above, the first code block only set the settings of Print. It only return a blank document If I tried calling doc.Print()